# undefined method image tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to call image tag in a model and return the image if it exists other wise return null like this :-

```
 def medium_avatar_exists?
    if self.avatar.present?
      image_tag self.avatar.thumb_medium_url
    else
      image_tag "missing-avatar-medium.png"
    end
  end
```

when I call this method from the view :- `current_user.medium_avatar_exist?`

I get an error saying undefined method image_tag what could be the issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use helper methods in model `image_tag` is an helper method and you are trying to use it in the model hence it gives an error.

Try following instead in your `application_helper.rb` or some other helpr you want

```
def medium_avatar_exists?(user)
  if user.avatar.present?
    image_tag user.avatar.thumb_medium_url
  else
    image_tag "missing-avatar-medium.png"
  end
end
```

OR  Just

```
def medium_avatar_exists?(user)
  image_tag (user.avatar.present? ? user.avatar.thumb_medium_url : "missing-avatar-medium.png")
end
```